# How do I fix the Uncommitted CATransaction warning

Tags: macos, core-animation

I have created a NSProgressIndicator Spinner using a custom NSView as shown below but get the Uncommitted CATransaction error shown further below.

I assume this is because of the background thread used for animation of the Spinner. Can anyone tell me:

a) is there something wrong with this spinner code using a background thread, and if so what is the alternative?
b) how do I prevent the CATransaction error?

```
//
//  Spinner.swift
//  Sample
//
//  Created by Duncan Groenewald on 18/12/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Duncan Groenewald. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa


class Spinner: NSView {
    // Some constants to control the animation
    let kAlphaWhenStopped: CGFloat =  0.15
    let kFadeMultiplier: CGFloat  =  0.85

    var position = 0
    var numFins: Int = 12
    var finColors = Array<NSColor>()
    //NSColor *_finColors;

    dynamic var animate: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            //FLog("called")
            if animate {
                startAnimation(self)
            } else {
                stopAnimation(self)
            }
        }
    }

    var isAnimating: Bool = false
    var isFadingOut: Bool = false
    var animationTimer: NSTimer? = nil
    var animationThread: NSThread? = nil

    var foreColor = NSColor.whiteColor()
    var backColor = NSColor.yellowColor()

    var displayedWhenStopped: Bool = true

    // For determinate mode
    var indeterminate: Bool = true
    var currentValue: Double = 0.0

    var color: NSColor? = nil
    var backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()

    var drawsBackground: Bool = true
    var usesThreadedAnimation: Bool = true
    var isIndeterminate: Bool = true
    //var doubleValue: Double = 0.0
    var maxValue: Double = 0.0

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)

        commonInit()
    }


    func commonInit() {
        position = 0;
        numFins = 12;

        isAnimating = false
        isFadingOut = false

        loadColors()

        backColor = NSColor.clearColor()
        drawsBackground = false


        displayedWhenStopped = true
        usesThreadedAnimation = true

        indeterminate = true
        currentValue = 0.0;
        maxValue = 100.0;
    }

    func loadColors() {
        //FLog("called")
        for var i=0; i<numFins; i++ {
            finColors.append(foreColor)

        }
    }
    override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        super.viewDidMoveToWindow()
        //FLog(" called")

        if self.hidden {
            self.actuallyStopAnimation()
        } else if isAnimating {
            self.actuallyStartAnimation()
        }

    }

    func startAnimation(sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        //FLog(" called")
        if !indeterminate {
            return
        }
        if isAnimating && !isFadingOut {
            return
        }

        self.actuallyStartAnimation()
    }

    func stopAnimation(sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        //FLog(" called")

        // animate to stopped state
        isFadingOut = true
    }

    /// Only the spinning style is implemented
    func setStyle(style: NSProgressIndicatorStyle)
    {
        if (NSProgressIndicatorStyle.SpinningStyle != style) {
            assert(false, "Non-spinning styles not available.")
        }
    }

    func setColorX(value: NSColor)
    {
       // FLog("called")

            //FLog("set foreColor \(value)")
            foreColor = value

            // generate all the fin colors, with the alpha components
            // they already have
            for var i=0; i<numFins; i++ {
                //FLog("set finColors")
                let alpha: CGFloat = finColors[i].alphaComponent
                finColors.append(foreColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(alpha))

            }

            self.needsDisplay = true

    }

    func setBackgroundColor(value: NSColor)
    {
        if backColor != value {

            backColor = value;
            self.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    func setDrawsBackground(value: Bool)
    {
        if drawsBackground != value {
            drawsBackground = value
        }
        self.needsDisplay = true
    }

    func setIndeterminate(isIndeterminate: Bool)
    {
        indeterminate = isIndeterminate;
        if !indeterminate && isAnimating {

            self.stopAnimation(self)
        }
        self.needsDisplay = true
    }

    func setDoubleValue(doubleValue: Double)
    {
        // Automatically put it into determinate mode if it's not already.
        if indeterminate {
            self.indeterminate = false
        }
        currentValue = doubleValue;
        self.needsDisplay = true
    }

    func setMaxValue(maxValue: Double)
    {
        self.maxValue = maxValue;
        self.needsDisplay = true
    }

    func setUsesThreadedAnimation(useThreaded: Bool)
    {
        if (self.usesThreadedAnimation != useThreaded) {
            self.usesThreadedAnimation = useThreaded;

            if (isAnimating) {
                // restart the timer to use the new mode
                self.stopAnimation(self)
                self.startAnimation(self)
            }
        }
    }

    func setDisplayedWhenStopped(displayedWhenStopped: Bool)
    {
        self.displayedWhenStopped = displayedWhenStopped;

        // Show/hide ourself if necessary
        if (!isAnimating) {
            if displayedWhenStopped && self.hidden {
                self.hidden = false
            }
            else if !displayedWhenStopped && !self.hidden {
                self.hidden = true
            }
        }
    }

    func updateFrame(sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        //FLog(" called \(position)")

        if self.position > 0 {
            self.position--
        }
        else {
            self.position = self.numFins - 1
        }

        // update the colors
        let minAlpha:CGFloat = self.displayedWhenStopped ? kAlphaWhenStopped : 0.01;

        for var i=0; i<numFins; i++ {

            // want each fin to fade exponentially over _numFins frames of animation
            var newAlpha: CGFloat = self.finColors[i].alphaComponent * kFadeMultiplier
            if newAlpha < minAlpha {
                newAlpha = minAlpha
            }
            self.finColors[i] = self.foreColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(newAlpha)
            //FLog(" finColor[\(i)] = ?")
        }

        if self.isFadingOut {
            //FLog(" isFadingOut ")
            // check if the fadeout is done
            var done = true
            for var i=0; i<self.numFins; i++ {
                //FLog(" fabs = \(fabs(self.finColors[i].alphaComponent - minAlpha))")
                if fabs(self.finColors[i].alphaComponent - minAlpha) > 0.01 {
                    done = false
                    break
                }

            }
            if done {
                self.actuallyStopAnimation()
            }
        }
        else {
            //FLog(" light up ")
            // "light up" the next fin (with full alpha)
            self.finColors[position] = self.foreColor
        }

        if self.usesThreadedAnimation {
            // draw now instead of waiting for setNeedsDisplay (that's the whole reason
            // we're animating from background thread)
            self.display()
        }
        else {
            self.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }


    func actuallyStartAnimation()
    {
        //FLog(" called")

        // Just to be safe kill any existing timer.
        self.actuallyStopAnimation()

        isAnimating = true
        isFadingOut = false

        // always start from the top
        position = 1

        if !self.displayedWhenStopped {
            self.hidden = false
        }

        if self.window != nil {
            FLog(" self.window != nil")
            // Why animate if not visible?  viewDidMoveToWindow will re-call this method when needed.
            if self.usesThreadedAnimation {
                animationThread = NSThread(target: self, selector: "animateInBackgroundThread", object: nil)
                animationThread?.start()
            }
            else {
                animationTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: NSTimeInterval(0.05), target: self, selector: "updateFrame:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


                NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.animationTimer!, forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes)
                NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.animationTimer!, forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
                NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.animationTimer!, forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode)
            }
        } else {
           //FLog(" self.window == nil")
    }
    }


    func actuallyStopAnimation() {
        //FLog(" called")

        isAnimating = false
        isFadingOut = false

        if !self.displayedWhenStopped {
            self.hidden = true
        }
        if self.animationThread != nil {
            // we were using threaded animation
            self.animationThread!.cancel()
            if !self.animationThread!.finished {
                NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSModalPanelRunLoopMode, beforeDate:NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.05))
            }

            self.animationThread = nil
        }
        else if self.animationTimer != nil {
            // we were using timer-based animation
            self.animationTimer!.invalidate()

            self.animationTimer = nil
        }
        self.needsDisplay = true
    }

    func generateFinColorsStartAtPosition(startPosition: Int)
    {
        for var i=0; i<self.numFins; i++ {
            let oldColor: NSColor = self.finColors[i]
            let alpha = oldColor.alphaComponent
            self.finColors[i] = self.foreColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(alpha)
        }
    }

    func animateInBackgroundThread()
    {
        //FLog(" called")
        // Set up the animation speed to subtly change with size > 32.
        // int animationDelay = 38000 + (2000 * ([self bounds].size.height / 32));

        // Set the rev per minute here
        let omega: Int = 100 // RPM
        let animationDelay = 60 * 1000000 / omega / numFins
        var poolFlushCounter: Int = 0

        do {
            //FLog(" this is called")
            updateFrame(nil)

            usleep(useconds_t(animationDelay))
            poolFlushCounter++;
            if poolFlushCounter > 256 {

                poolFlushCounter = 0
            }
        } while (!NSThread.currentThread().cancelled)
        //FLog(" animateInBackgroundThread finished !")
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        //FLog(" called")
        let size: NSSize = self.bounds.size
        //FLog(" size \(size)")
        var theMaxSize: CGFloat = 0.0

        // Set the size to the minimum dimension
        if (size.width >= size.height) {
            theMaxSize = size.height
        } else {
            theMaxSize = size.width
        }

        if self.drawsBackground {
            backColor.set()

            NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).fill()
        }

        if let currentContext = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext() {

            var context = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()!.CGContext


            NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()

            // Move the CTM so 0,0 is at the center of our bounds
            let w2 = self.bounds.size.width / 2.0
            let h2 = self.bounds.size.height / 2.0
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,w2,h2)

            if (indeterminate) {
                //FLog(" indeterminate")
                var path = NSBezierPath()

                let lineWidth: CGFloat = 0.0859375 * theMaxSize; // should be 2.75 for 32x32
                let lineStart: CGFloat = 0.234375 * theMaxSize; // should be 7.5 for 32x32
                let lineEnd: CGFloat = 0.421875 * theMaxSize;  // should be 13.5 for 32x32

                path.lineWidth = lineWidth
                path.lineCapStyle = NSLineCapStyle.RoundLineCapStyle
                path.moveToPoint(NSMakePoint(0, lineStart))
                path.lineToPoint(NSMakePoint(0, lineEnd))

                for var i = 0; i<numFins; i++ {
                    if isAnimating {
                        finColors[i].set()
                    } else {
                        foreColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(kAlphaWhenStopped).set()
                    }

                    path.stroke()

                    // we draw all the fins by rotating the CTM, then just redraw the same segment again
                    let r: CGFloat = 6.282185 / CGFloat(numFins)
                    CGContextRotateCTM(context, r)
                }

            } else {
                //FLog(" !indeterminate")
                let lineWidth:CGFloat = 1 + (0.01 * theMaxSize)
                let circleRadius:CGFloat  = (theMaxSize - lineWidth) / 2.1
                let circleCenter:NSPoint  = NSMakePoint(0, 0)
                foreColor.set()
                var path = NSBezierPath()
                path.lineWidth = lineWidth
                path.appendBezierPathWithOvalInRect(NSMakeRect(-circleRadius, -circleRadius, circleRadius*2, circleRadius*2))
                path.stroke()

                path = NSBezierPath()

                let endAngle = 90.0 - (360.0 * currentValue / maxValue)

                path.appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter(circleCenter, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: 90.0, endAngle: CGFloat(endAngle), clockwise:true)


                path.lineToPoint(circleCenter)
                path.fill()

            }
            NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
        }
    }

}
```

CoreAnimation warning:

```
CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; created by:
0   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff845180ea _ZN2CA11Transaction4pushEv + 312
1   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff84517f8a _ZN2CA11Transaction15ensure_implicitEv + 276
2   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8451d313 _ZN2CA5Layer13thread_flags_EPNS_11TransactionE + 37
3   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff84526941 _ZN2CA5Layer13needs_displayEv + 45
4   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8452690c -[CALayer needsDisplay] + 21
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff853576a3 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 1078
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff85356340 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:] + 1417
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff85337de6 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1216
8   Sample                              0x000000010004d6fd _TFC20SISU_Sample7Spinner11updateFramefS0_FGSqPSs9AnyObject__T_ + 2717
9   Sample                              0x000000010004f78b _TFC20SISU_Sample7Spinner25animateInBackgroundThreadfS0_FT_T_ + 219
10  Sample                              0x000000010004f8c2 _TToFC20SISU_Sample7Spinner25animateInBackgroundThreadfS0_FT_T_ + 34
11  Foundation                          0x00007fff91b02b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff87f5b2fc _pthread_body + 131
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff87f5b279 _pthread_body + 0
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff87f594b1 thread_start + 13
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are changing the state of your NSView in the background thread.
You can't do that.

You *may* be able to draw the view if you call lockFocusIfCanDraw, although in the end I've always abandoned these attempts...  you *cannot* change the state safely.

```
if ( [view lockFocusIfCanDraw] )
{
    [view drawRect:[view bounds]];
    [view unlockFocus];
}
```

If it were me, I would abandon this approach... your main thread should only be used for UI interaction & drawing.

Instead, any task that takes more than 0.2 seconds should be done in a background thread, but drawing should not be done in a background thread.
Unfortunately this is also easier said than done.

Comment: Mmm, well I am not actually calling drawRect from the background thread, I am calling 'self.display()' or 'self.needsDisplay = true'.  The latter works fine but 'self.display()' gives this error.  I assume this is because calling 'self.display()' results in 'drawRect()' being called from the same thread as 'self.display()' was called from.  So is there any benefit in dispatching 'self.display()' to the main thread (with wait) over simply setting 'self.needsDisplay = true' ?